# How to connect a generator and LED device of different polarities?

Tags: led, polarity, reverse-polarity

I have a device that generates light impulses when connected to a LED device. The intensity of the light is regulated by a potentiometer, within the generator. There are 2 independent channels. The generator works with "Common Ground" polarity, but my LED device works with "Common Power" polarity and doesn't work at all. To my eyes it seems the LED device is just a bunch of LEDs, with no other electronic parts. I tried to change the connections, with only one channel working at best. I naively imagine the circuits are:
[image]
Is it possible to change the polarity to make the CP LEDs work with the CG generator and make it still possible to be able to control the light intensity?

Comment: Common Anode to V+ with series R on Cathode to each driver

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thank you but I don't understand, I'm sorry. Are Anode / Cathode the positive / negative outputs of the driver? Then to me it seems the "CG" driver has a common Cathode. Not sure what does "series R" mean - I'm a real amateur :)

Comment: High side driver needs to be inverted to low side of diodes (cathode) with current limited by voltage difference over series resistance as in ohms law